# What is the difference between fakerphp/faker and fzaninotto/faker?

Tags: laravel, faker

I'm new(ish) to Laravel and I've been trying to get a clear understanding of how to use Faker to generate my test data. One of the things that's really confusing me right now is the different versions of Faker that I'm seeing in code examples. Some of them use fzaninotto/faker while others use fakerphp/faker (which I see is built into my Laravel 9.41.0 app).

What is the difference between the two packages and which one should I be using? Or will I need both due to differences between what fakes each package can generate?

I'd really appreciate some advice on this matter. I have a suspicion that the fzaninotto version is an older version of the fakerphp version and that I should simply use fakerphp and just think "fakerphp" whenever I see examples that use fzaninotto but maybe that is just wishful thinking on my part....

Comment: Well the first is a fork of the later, the fzaninotto/Faker repository is archived and the project is hosted on FakerPHP/Faker repository now, you should always use FakerPHP/Faker. Read https://marmelab.com/blog/2020/10/21/sunsetting-faker.html